# Jquery Validate default settings doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

Default settings don't work. The "setdefaults" command doesn't do anything.

My page may have a lot of forms and things going on. But for whatever reason, it always ignores the display:none "select box" "select#ffe". FFE is a Chosen select box, so it hides the select box and thus the form doesn't validate it.

In the rules section, textboxes validate fine, but the select box doesn't validate.

Here's my jquery.ready:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });
        var validator = $("select#ffe").closest("form").data('validator');
        console.log("V1: ", validator.settings.ignore);

        //validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(select)";
        console.log("V1: ", validator.settings.ignore);
        $("select#ffe").closest("form").validate({
            settings: {
                ignore: ":hidden:not(select)"
                },
            rules: {
          //....... skipping some rules.......
});

$("select#ffe").rules("add", { required: true }); // chosen invisible select box

        console.log("V1: ", validator.settings.ignore);
```

The V1 console log doesn't ever change from "V1: :hidden".

If you try to set "validator.settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(select)" [commented because it doesnt work] it will give you a different error on form submit saying it cannot read the "validator.settings.rules" because it is undefined. A bizarre bug in jquery.validate.js because it says validator.settings is empty and it's caused by you setting ignore directly.

The error targets the if statement here in jquery.validate.js:

```
staticRules: function( element ) {
        var rules = {};
        var validator = $.data(element.form, "validator");
        if ( validator.settings.rules ) { // BROKEN BECAUSE VALIDATOR.SETTINGS IS EMPTY.
```

I'm using:

jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1

jQuery 1.11.1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see via console log, `.setDefaults()` is working:  **http://jsfiddle.net/rop59zw4/**

---

Your selector is wrong... `":hidden:not(select)"` should be `":hidden:not('select')"`.

The quotes around `select` were missing so it was looking for a variable called `select` instead of the `select` element tags.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/rop59zw4/**

---

FYI - There is no such `.validate()` option called `settings`.  Any option placed inside of `settings` would be disregarded or possibly break things...

```
$('form').validate({
      settings: {  // <-- not a valid option
          ignore: ":hidden:not('select')"  // <- not considered at all
      },
      rules: { ...
```

This demo shows that anything within the non-existant `settings` object is totally  disregarded.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/gmmauz9z/**

---

If you've already set `ignore` within `.setDefaults()`, then setting it within `.validate()` would over-ride `.setDefaults()`.  This allows you to have a default set of options for multiple forms with the ability to over-ride on an individual form.  (NOTE: the `.validate()` method cannot be called multiple times on the same form.  Only the first instance is used and all others ignored.)

This demo shows `.validate()` options taking precedence over `.setDefaults` options.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/bjgb31tj/**

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I can't even change the default settings of jquery.validate. I can't even change it manually. It still says ":hidden" for "ignore". It never changes to the select one. So this is even before the problem you mention. ALSO in your fiddle using 'select' vs select doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Dexter, look at my answer again.  You have other issues that are breaking things.  See the console log here:  http://jsfiddle.net/01ww4nna/

Comment: yeah I mean your fiddle seems to work regardless. But in mine, the chosen is somehow interfering, maybe because of AJAX or chosen's magic. the validator.settings.ignore doesn't seem to change to not select.

Comment: @Dexter, there are quite a few questions on SO about integrating Chosen with jQuery Validate.  It can be done successfully.  I doubt that Chosen is interfering with the `ignore` option.  Likely, you still have a minor error in a selector or typo someplace.

Comment: I believe my problem is a lot more complex because there is some other validate being called in another js file. i'm looking for it. I don't think it's you, I think it's me :O.

Comment: Lesson learned: do NOT have multiple ".validate()"s anywhere in other files!!!! They could be in another file you forgot.